# Solve the Canonical Form: $-8\xi\eta U_{\xi\eta}+\xi U_\xi+3\eta U_\eta =0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, canonical-transformation

Solve the Canonical Form: $-8\xi\eta U_{\xi\eta}+\xi U_\xi+3\eta U_\eta =0$

I can solve ordinary canonical form, but it is too hard for me, Can you help me solve out or give me some hints?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: also $\xi$ and $\eta$ are unusual, so would you mind reformulate with $x,y$ if these are real or with $m,n$ if these are integers. As it, it is hard to see which is indexed and which is a multiplication.